# How to unit test Dart in Phpstorm

Tags: unit-testing, dart, phpstorm

I installed the dart plugin, set the SDK home path to the dart-sdk folder, configured the scope and checked the 'Dart SDK enabled' option in Phpstorm 6.0.3. Next, I created a dart file in a 'test' directory with the following code (obviously I added the dependency unittest in my pubspec.yaml and ran pub get):

```
library mytests;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

main(){
    test('my test', (){
        expect(1+1, equals(2));
    });
}
```

When I run this unit test however (by right clicking inside the file and selecting 'Run Test: my test', an error is outputted in the unit testing window stating the following:

```
C:/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --ignore-unrecognized-flags --package-root=C:/Users/myname/dart/pokerdart/test/packages/ C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\jetbrains_unit_config.dart
Testing started at 18:55 ...
'file:///C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Temp/jetbrains_unit_config.dart': error: line 1 pos 1: unresolved implicit call to super constructor 'Configuration()'
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
^
```

When I run the test using powershell it just works... Am I missing something/doing something wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WEB-9636](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9636) is fixed in version 7. Please try upgrading to PHPStorm 7.1.3. Or, even better, try PHPStorm 8 EAP (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) - Dart support has been improved there